# Magento : Fatal error : Call to a member function getFrontend() on a non-object

Tags: magento

Hi i am a fresher in magento. I have installed a new theme in magento and it was working fine. but when i navigate to products individual page, an error was showing
'Call to a member function getFrontend() on a non-object'.....

Thanks for support in Advance

Comment: Please clear cache and reindexing.

Comment: I have cleared the cache and Reindexed,but no change..

Answer (score 3):

This was ask a long time ago, but I wanted to provide my input.

I had this same error and it was from moving code that I new worked in production to a staging server.  It turns out there was a custom attribute added to my attribute set that didn't get transferred over to staging and was causing the error.

Comment: And how did you manage to fix it? I'm having similar issues and I noticed this is caused by a custom attribute.

Comment: You have to create the custom attribute in the Magento backend.  It's in catalog->manage attributes

Comment: I see, but it's not the Product attributes I'm worried about, I'm having this problem with Customer Attributes.

Comment: customer attributes can also be created from admin, it it advisable that we should create all our custom attributes from the installers, so that we don't have to create it each time on multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

in you new theme there may be error in code of list.phtml
you can check that page located in app/design/frontend/default or your theme /catalog/product/list.phtml

you can compare the code with your previous theme by following the above location and do the required modifacation.

Answer (score 1):

try use default magento theme, if no problem found maybe there is missing files on your theme